# Difference between managed C++ and C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, programming-languages, managed-c++

The second question is: When do I use what of these two?

Comment: I think you should look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57923/what-exactly-is-managed-code).

Comment: Managed Extensions for C++ or just Managed C++ is a now deprecated Microsoft set of deviations from C++, including grammatical and syntactic extensions, keywords and attributes, to bring the C++ syntax and language to the .NET Framework. These extensions allowed C++ code to be targeted to the Common Language Runtime (CLR) in the form of managed code as well as continue to interoperate with native code. Managed C++ was not a complete standalone, or full-fledged programming language. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B#.E2.80.A6to_C.23

Answer (score 76, accepted):

When not specified, C++ is unmanaged C++, compiled to machine code. In unmanaged C++ you must manage memory allocation manually.

Managed C++ is a language invented by Microsoft, that compiles to bytecode run by the .NET Framework. It uses mostly the same syntax as C++ (hence the name) but is compiled in the same way as C# or VB.NET; basically only the syntax changes, e.g. using '->' to point to a member of an object (instead of '.' in C#), using '::' for namespaces, etc.

Managed C++ was made to ease transition from classic C++ to the .NET Framework. It is not intended to be used to start new projects (C# is preferred).

Comment: A caution on the advice to not use managed c++ for new projects. From Visual Studio 2008 onwards Managed c++ has some features that are superior to c#. These relate to the handling of IDisposable objects. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235315.aspx

Comment: Managed C++ and C++/CLI are two different beasts.  Managed C++ is a hideous extension to C++ that should never have seen the light of day.  C++/CLI is officially a separate language, so new keywords can be added, and is much nicer to work with.

Comment: So is C++/CLI managed or not?

Comment: @KyleDelaney C++/CLI is managed.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, Managed C++ doesn't compile to bytecode, but a mixed mode executable switching between bytecode and native code, depending on what objects are being used. It is possible to create a purely managed executable using C++/CLI if none of "unsafe" C++ features (like none of CRT or STL) are used.

Answer (score 14):

"Managed C++" refers to a language that was included in Visual Studio.NET/Visual Studio.NET 2003. It has since [been deprecated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B#.E2.80.A6to_C.23), with the latest .NET C++ being C++/CLI.

Answer (score 3):

You can code native C++ two different ways. The first is compiling directly to machine code with just the operating system between you and the *platform* (*hardware*). The second native coding is done with [MFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library) (Microsoft Foundation Classes). This is the same as the first example except for the use of MFC.

Managed C++ uses the CLR (Common Language Runtime). The CLR along with the .NET framework class libraries make up the .NET Framework. This managed C++/CLI standard uses the .NET framework along with the [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) (Microsoft Intermediate Language). This standard works by mapping to machine code only when the program is executing by the use of a just in time compiler. If your code will be running on different hardware platforms the use of managed code will be much easier. As with all thing there is a slight price to pay for convenience, as native code will run faster.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be using managed C++ when want to use a native C++ class library from managed code. In this case you wrap unmanaged classes in managed C++ ones, then you use them in any CLR language.

Answer (score 0):

Managed C++ means that memory allocation, management, garbage collection is handled by the virtual machine. Whereas in "regular" C++ you would have to allocate and deallocate memory.