# Call C# function from native C++ or C

Tags: c#, c++-cli, pinvoke

I'm try to follow this steps: [Calling C# from C++, Reverse P/Invoke, Mixed Mode DLLs and C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068762/calling-c-sharp-from-c-reverse-p-invoke-mixed-mode-dlls-and-c-cli?rq=1)
1. I make C# Dll named TestLib:

```
namespace TestLib
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public float Add(float a, float b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

2. Then I create C++/CLI Dll named WrapperLib and add reference to C# TestLib.

```
// WrapperLib.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace TestLib;

namespace WrapperLib {

    public class WrapperClass
    {
    float Add(float a, float b)
        {
        TestClass^ pInstance = gcnew TestClass();
        //pInstance
        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
        return pInstance->Add(a, b);
        }
    };
}
```

C+
3. For check tis example I've create C++/CLI console application and try to call this code:

```
// ConsoleTest.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace WrapperLib;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    WrapperClass cl1 = new WrapperClass();

    return 0;
}
```

But I get a few errors:

```
error C2065: 'WrapperClass' : undeclared identifier C:\Projects\TestSolution\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest.cpp    11  1   ConsoleTest
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'cl1' C:\Projects\TestSolution\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest.cpp    11  1   ConsoleTest
error C2065: 'cl1' : undeclared identifier  C:\Projects\TestSolution\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest.cpp    11  1   ConsoleTest
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WrapperClass'   C:\Projects\TestSolution\ConsoleTest\ConsoleTest.cpp    11  1   ConsoleTest
```

Well I know somewhere I missed, but where?

Comment: If the compiler told you "hey, got a few errors, please fix" where would you look first? :) Please tell us what the errors are.

Comment: Fixed. I've add VS output. How to right call this function from native C++ or C?

Answer (score 2):

According to @Ben Voigt suggestion I believe that your code should look somewhat like this:

```
// ConsoleTest.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "WrapperLib.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace WrapperLib;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    float result;
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
    WrapperClass cl1;

    result = cl1.Add(1, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't include the header file of your wrapper library, the C++ compiler will never find its functions and you will keep getting the errors that you displayed earlier.

Comment: My WrapperLib project contain WrapperLib.h with code and WrapperLib.cpp only with: #include "stdafx.h" #include "WrapperLib.h" Is it right?

Comment: Yes I believe that is correct, however you need to #include your WrapperLib header file into your main project (the one you are using to test it). As @Mark Simith said above, in native C++ it doesn't matter if you did or did not reference another project, you still need to include the header files.

Answer (score 1):

That's not good C++, looks like Java or C#.

The correct syntax to create a new object in C++/CLI is

```
WrapperClass cl1;
```

or

```
WrapperClass^ cl1 = gcnew WrapperClass();
```

C++ has stack semantics, you have to tell the compiler whether you want a local object that is automatically disposed at the end of the function (first option), or a handle that can live longer (second option, using `^` and `gcnew`).

Comment: I try with WrapperClass^ cl1 = gcnew WrapperClass(); but I get errors: Error 1 error C2065: 'WrapperClass' : undeclared identifier 
error C2065: 'cl1' : undeclared identifier 
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'WrapperClass'

Comment: @Superjet100: You also need `#include "WrapperLib.h"`

Comment: But in this test console aplication I don't have #include "WrapperLib.h"

Comment: @Superjet100: Oh, it's a separate project?  Then add a reference to the project where `WrapperLib::WrapperClass` is defined.

Comment: Yes, I've added reference in console C++/CLI application to C++/CLI wrapper library.

Comment: For native classes from another dll (like WrapperClass), to make them visible in your translation unit you need to #include their header file (just like standard C++ code).  For managed classes from another dll, you only need to add a reference to the project (just like in C#).

Comment: @Superjet: Is `WrapperLib.h` actually getting compiled in the library project?  Introduce a syntax error, see if the compiler notices.

Comment: Where I must put code realization? In CPP file? And what must contain H file?