# Visual Studio 2010 : How to get code to be "managed"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, metrics

I work on a little C++ open source project.
I need to get some metrics out of it.
To do so, Visual Studio requires the code to be "managed".

Simple question (expect simple answer) : how do I get metrics from native projects ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Not so simple.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114238/difference-between-managed-c-and-c

Comment: Thanks :) Any idea how could I get the metrics I need ?

Comment: That's why I posted my previous comment.. Are you talking about managed extensions or managed cli?

Comment: Forget about the managed thing. I just need to get some metrics out of the project. That's my focus.

Comment: AFAIK the usual wisdom is to avoid "managed C++" unless you're completely out of options

Comment: have a look at this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/f25ab262-cb10-417a-89e8-10bf5d77bdf5/ ^^

Answer (score 0):

Change your project properties to "Use Common Language-Runtime (`/clr`)".

This will cause the compiler to emit .NET metadata for functions and variables in the program, and the profiler/analyzer relies on this metadata.

Sometimes the metadata is less complete for standard C++ code than for .NET types.  And you surely don't want to rewrite everything over to C++/CLI, managed types, .NET runtime, garbage collection.

But trying a compile with `/clr` enabled shouldn't hurt anything.