# How to identify whether a project is managed c++ project or unmanaged c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have some c++ projects where it consists of both managed and unmanaged c++ projects.

How do I identify which project is managed c++ and which project is unmanaged c++ type.

Along with above could someone brief me what exactly these managed and unmanaged c++ means.

Comment: [Difference between managed c++ and c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114238/difference-between-managed-c-and-c)

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to the project properties, General "block"
2. Project Defaults Section
3. Common Language Runtime Support option

If this option is **not** set to "No Common Language Runtime Support", then it is "managed" C++, which in any modern version of Visual Studio is C++/CLI (unless the setting is "Old Syntax", then it is the original managed C++ syntax).

References:
[Managed Extensions for C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B) (old syntax)
[C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)

Comment: In VS 2019 it is under C/C++->General->Common Language RunTime Support

Answer (score 3):

Go to project properties -> C++ -> Command Line

If it contains `/clr` then the project is build under C++/CLI, otherwise it's "unmanaged".

Comment: `/clr` is not the only option for "managed" c++, at least in Visual Studio 2017.