# Is there way to inherit __interface with another __interface on C++/cli?

Tags: inheritance, interface, c++-cli

I would like to implement following interfaces so whatever that inherits from `iB` would be able to use both `methodA()` and `methodB()` and whatever that inherits only `iA` would not have access to `methodB()` on C++. Seems like very standard interface inheriting another interface.

However, I get an error building stating that "a standard class cannot derive from a managed class"

```
__interface iA
{
    methodA();
}

__interface iB : iA
{
    methodB();
}
```

Does anybody have any clue on how I can resolve this issue?

EDIT : I am using managed C++. However, why would iB become standard and iA become managed?

Comment: Yes you can. Give it a shot.

Comment: "managed" is a term from Microsoft's .NET framework. You're not building this as plain C++.

Comment: `__interface` does not exist in standard C++

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114238/difference-between-managed-c-and-c

Comment: That is correct that I am using managed C++. However, why would iB become standard and iA become managed?

Comment: Is this _all_ you have? Do you have any classes that try to implement either of these interfaces?

Comment: I have a dialog class that inherits CDialog and iB

Comment: Are you certain _that's_ not the problem? A non-managed class implementing a managed interface?

Comment: I have been implementing class that inherits iA as is without any issue. The error is only when I inherit iA from iB. If I detach iA and iB and inherit the interface separately to the class of my interest, there are no issue.

Comment: What version of Visual C++ is this?  You should be using `interface class` in C++/CLI.  "Managed C++" is dead and buried 12 years ago.

Comment: You can use under c++-cli `public interface class IA { ... };` and `public interface class IB : IA { ... };`