# How to represent System.double in unmanaged C++?

Tags: c++, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

I'm writing a standalone app for Solidworks using API in Unmanaged C++ and facing some kind of a problem.
There're methods for obtaining annotations' position coordinates on the drawing sheet - IGetPosition and GetPosition. Both a stated to have arrays of 3 elements as RetVals. But Visual Studio does not accept me to pass array of doubles to IGetPosition.

[Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2IWw.png)

Meanwhile, API Help has examples for definitions in C# and C++/CLI:

```
System.double IGetPosition();
```

[System.double](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WNRh.png) [SW API IGetPosition](http://help.solidworks.com/2018/english/api/sldworksapi/SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks~SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.IAnnotation~IGetPosition.html)
As I have figured out, System.double is not jast a double, but a struct in Managed C++. I am not famailiar with this stuff as I'm just a beginner.
So the question is: How can I represent System.double in Unmanaged code to be accepted as an IGetPosition &parameter?

BTW: GetPosition method takes a VARIANT, but returns a safearray of rank[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2IWw.png), which seems not to be compatible with 3 values of XYZ.
Also found out something about Marshalization. Is that the right way? If so, would you be so kind to provide me with an example?

Comment: What is _unmanaged C++_? Please [clarify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48807688/edit). There is a type `double` in standard C++.

Comment: In C# there is `double` and `System.Double` there is no `System.double`.

Comment: When not specified, C++ is unmanaged C++, compiled to machine code. In unmanaged C++ you must manage memory allocation manually. ©https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114238/difference-between-managed-c-and-c

Comment: @keith I do not use C#, System.double is stated as I wrote it in SW API help. I've updated the post with an url and screenshot.

Comment: @Sergey Kolesnik, that documentation is probably wrong. It likely means `double` which is a *value type*. `System.Double` is not a value type, it's a `struct`. `System.double` is just erroneous: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double. As @Ron said, use C++ `double`.

Comment: @Ron of course there is. And the method accepts double as a parameter, yet it also returns only 1 value, when I need 3. It doesn't accept an array of doubles (see Pic1). Since Sytem::Double is a struct, it can store 3 values.

Comment: @keith Documentation says this method to return an Array of XYZ, and having only one double returned for 3 coordinates is no go. System.Double is a struct - I've figured it out and wrote in the post. in C# it takes a struct System.Double and returns a struck, probably. With XYZ. So how can I implement it in usual c++?

Comment: @Sergey Kolesnik, you have declared `double XYZ[3]`. `&XYZ` is of type `double**`. Try `XYZ` or `&XYZ[0]` if you must.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that C++ doesn't allow arrays as function parameters or return value. However, it allows pointers, and arrays *decay* to pointers. In fact, `new double[3]` creates an array and returns a pointer.

In particular, arrays decay to to a pointer to their first element. That is to say, `double XYZ[3]` decays to a `double*` pointing to `XYZ[0]`.

You used `&XYZ`. That is also a valid expression, but it gives you a pointer to the array - not to its first element. Just drop the `&`, and use  `pAnnf->IGetPosition(XYZ)`.

Comment: Thanks for an explanation, I didn't know that about arrays. It accepted XYZ as a parameter. But it didn't make things better. It retirns an Array of 0.1 0 0. Firstly, why would it change the precision, because earlier it was 0.12**** (if it did). Secondly, returning 1 value of 3 may confirm that this lib is actually messed up, but still it is doubtfull.