# How do I link a C++ program to a C# DLL outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I have a simple C++ program which calls a C# DLL.  It sends and receives a string.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

char* callCsDLL(char* arg) {
    // arg will be passed to C# DLL method
    // and result will contain a string reply

    // Copy a new System::String^ from char*
    System::String^ clrString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(arg);

    // Call C# function
    System::String^ t = Namespace::Class::run(clrString);

    // Create new std::string from System::String^
    std::string cppString = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(t);

    // Copy C++ string to the result
    char* result = new char[cppString.length() + 1];
    strcpy(result, cppString.c_str()); 
    return result;
}
```

Inside Visual Studio 2017, this is quite easy to do, use C++ CLR, just add the C# DLL to the references in the C++ project, and build.  It's almost magic.

How would I link these together outside of Visual Studio, that is, using the command line?  Could I avoid MSBUILD altogether?  The resulting executable should simply use the DLL.

Comment: What do you mean _outside of Visual Studio_? Using MSBuild from the command line?

Comment: You haven't a native c++ program. You have an managed c++ program which uses a C# *.dll. Here's an explanation of the differences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114238/difference-between-managed-c-and-c So when you want to create a native c++ program I belive you have to write a COM wrapper around you C# *.dll and use it.

Comment: Such is the trouble with magic, you first have to understand what you did before you can make such unrealistic demands.  What you have *not* done is write any C++ code, linking it is indeed the wall that the approach crashes into at a hundred miles an hour.  It is the worst possible way to do this kind of interop, don't follow the advice [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17131801/17034) before you looked at the other ways.  Exporting the function is the crucial step.