# What is Managed/Unmanaged .net code and what difference does it make to me?

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged, managed

I see the terms managed and unmanaged used a fair bit around here.  Searching online I can get a fuzzy notion of what they are, but what I really need to know is how it affects me as C# desktop app developer?  How do I know which I'm dealing with at any point and how does it change my approach to that code?

#### Duplicate

> [What is managed/unmanaged code in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334326/what-is-managed-unmanaged-code-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed code is code that needs the .NET framework to run... unmanaged code doesn't. If you are writing code in C# you are writing managed code. You might interface with unmanaged code if you use Pinvoke, but if you stick to pure C# your application will be all managed code.

Comment: @Jon T: Thanks, Jon, that's the nice succinct sort of answer I was looking for.