# is there any difference between .Net Native code execution vs machine code execution

Tags: c#, .net, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I'm getting so crazy on this topic. Just wanna to understand the execution part of codes developed in .net.

Execution of Native codes and machine codes are same or different? how its executing, want to know detailed information

I've searched many sites and blogs but not getting clear picture of those question. please help me to understand this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ...and see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3434252/961113

Comment: need to know execution process of those native and machine codes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/95635/961113