# How to launch any application with own UI Design vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, operating-system, exe

I use this code :

```
Shared Sub OpenApplication(ByVal ApplicationPath As String)
    Dim p As Process
    Dim ShowForm As New Form
    Dim FormPanel As New Panel
    FormPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    ShowForm.Controls.Add(FormPanel)
    p = Process.Start(ApplicationPath)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, FormPanel.Handle)
    ShowForm.Show()
End Sub
```

but it run the application inside the panel with the border.
if i make my own virtual operating system, how do i change the border to none?
like windows 7 have their own form border, windows 8 and mac too.
but I make my own form border. it's graphic, how can I make the application use my border?

this is some example(i cannot post image) :

[Windows 8 Notepad with Their UI Design (it's Form Border for me)](http://40-89-67-30-21.weebly.com//files/theme/300px-W8Notepad.png)

[Windows 7 Notepad with Their UI Design](http://40-89-67-30-21.weebly.com//files/theme/notepad-7.png)

And this is my UI Design :

(sorry I cannot insert more that 2 links, delete space in http:"Space"//)

http: //40-89-67-30-21.weebly.com//files/theme/Notepad.png

how can I Make like this when double click notepad.exe or another .exe file in my virtual os? (this is edited version !) :

http: //40-89-67-30-21.weebly.com//files/theme/Notepad_edited.png

it's run the exe but with my own UI Design. How can I do like that?

Comment: Do you really mean virtual OS or just a theme?

Comment: I make virtual os with desktop, file explore, taskbar but can open an .exe file. when I open the exe file, if i'm in windows 7 it will use windows 7 UI design but I want to use my own Design.

Answer (score 0):

By default 3rd party applications don't support their re-branding by 4th party developers and even OS-specific coding conventions don't force them to do so, except for support for branding the OS, like respecting [system colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemcolors(v=vs.110).aspx), [accessibility features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350483(v=vs.110).aspx#Visual_UI_Design) etc.

In order to implement this you'd have to do a lots of low-level hacking, intercept UI messages (like [WM_NCCALCSIZE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [WM_PAINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145213(v=vs.85).aspx)) etc. or replace complete libraries containing the UI drawing API (like [GDI32.DLL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145203(v=vs.85).aspx)) with your own.

All of this requires precise work, good understanding of the various low-level aspects and code well-coordinated with the rest of the system and approximately few thousands of lines of code, including some [native (not managed) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434202/what-is-the-difference-between-native-code-machine-code-and-assembly-code).

It's doable, but not simple, see e.g. [Stardock's WindowBlinds](http://www.stardock.com/products/windowblinds/)

See also:

- Google search `windows skins`