# How can i make a portable C++ program for Windows with GUI, independent from .NET or other Libs?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, portability, windows

I want to make a **C++** program **with Graphical User Interface**, to be running on **Windows** platforms.

I want it to be **independent from any libraries like .NET**.

The reason I want this is because I want this program to be able to run everywhere, in every version of Windows (XP, VISTA, 7 - 32 & 64bit) without the user to be bound to have already installed a library like .NET.

Also, I want it to be **portable**: the whole program to consist from only one exe file.

So to summarize:

***How can I make an one-exe-file GUI C++ program, able to run on all versions of Windows, without the need of pre-installed libraries on Windows from the user that uses it?***

I have already MS Visual C++ 2010 Express and Eclipse with Cygwin's G++ compiler installed on my system.

Notice: I don't mind to use any libraries for windows GUI design **if there is a way to embed them** inside the executable file of the program.

Comment: check out [cinder](http://libcinder.org/features/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use a library that can be statically linked (MFC, WTL) or use Win32 API directly.

Comment: How can i make this with Visual C++ '10 Express? When i create a new Project of Win32 Application there is no choice of _static linking_... Neither i can select MFC or WTL...

Comment: MFC/ATL are not included in the Express versions

Comment: There is a way to use WTL with express versions of Visual Studio. For instance: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12705/Using-WTL-with-Visual-C-2005-Express-Edition

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic (or any other), let's say that i use the native Win32 API in my program. Please tell me **1)** How can i make/define a static linking of Win32 libraries in VC++ '10 Express for my executable? **2)** What type of project should i select from the wizard? **3)** Will I be able to use the Toolbox to add buttons/labels/menus and other controls to my Form (window)? The code will be written automatically in source view?

Comment: @MinimalTech: you don't link the Win32 libraries statically. but you need to specify statically linked runtime.

Comment: @MinimalTech: "Win32 libraries" are Windows. You don't statically link Windows to your program. However, as Cheers... mentions, you need to statically link C/C++ runtime; another option would be to not link to the C/C++ runtime at all.

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic yes I understand, I agree with you, but how can I do it? That's what I'm asking from the beginning...

Comment: @MinimalTech: Under Project Settings, C/C++, Code Generation, there is an option "Runtime Library". Pick the versions without "DLL", i.e. /MT and /MTd for release and debug builds respectively.

Answer (score 1):

[WxWidgets](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_WxWidgets_with_MSVC_%282%29#Static_Compilation) have static linking capability, never tried it myself.

Comment: UldisK, can i use this library with static linking without any legal issues? Also, will I be able to use the Toolbox to add buttons/labels menus and other controls to my Form (window)? The code will be written automatically in source view?

Comment: The library is licensed under modified LGPL. If understand correctly, one of the modifications are, that it can be static linked. I think I have seen some form builders out there, but I haven't used WxWidgets for a long time and newer with them, so I don't know how good they are.

Answer (score 1):

If you want portabiliy, and yet don't want to depend on 3rd party libraries... well you'll have to provide portability yourself! Don't do it! As adviced by OneOfOne, use **Qt** and be impressed how simple yet powerful it is. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

You can also use [Qt5](http://qt-project.org/doc/), works great on windows and when you figure out that windows isn't the only OS out there, you can easily port it to everything else.

License issues : [Proprietary Source code + LGPL Source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10179181/145587)

Comment: I think there were some leagal concerns on static linking with qt if the application is closed source... question does not state anything about that, but should be mentioned ..