# Mixed Code (native, managed): how does it (technically) interoperate?

Tags: java, c++, native, managed

I basically understand the idea of managed and native code and their [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855756/difference-between-native-and-managed-code). But how is it technically possible for them to communicate with each other? Imagine the following example:

I got some static or dynamic c++ library which is compiled for a specific platform. Now I write a Java Programm. Inside this code I call the library functions with the 'native' keyword. I build a jar file with the bytecode and the c++ library files will stay separate. The result will no longer be platform-independent.

1. But how does the java programm know if the called native methods exists?
2. How is the whole programmcode executed during runtime? I know that the bytecode will be interpreted or compiled with JIT.
3. How does this all fit in the sandboxing paradigm? Is the native code also executed inside the sandbox?
4. Does it work because both (java and c++) code is machine code in the end?

Maybe this is a dumb question. But I was always wondering...

EDIT: I got 3 good answers. really can't decide which helped me the most. But i will mark this question as answered to close this topic from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It doesn't know until you call the method. The native code resides in a .DLL or .so; the java runtime looks for specific entry points that correspond to the native methods you created (if you're using JNI, there's a tool that can parse the methods and create function stubs that'll result in those entry points when compiled). If the wanted entry point is not there, an exception will be thrown.
2. The code generated by the JIT is not entirely self-suficient; it has to call external native code (both for low-level runtime routines or OS services) from time to time. The same mechanism is used to invoke the code for your native methods.
3. No. You can do everything you'd do in a pure C/C++ program there. The only things that'll stop it from doing any damage are external security measures you have (login privilege restrictions, other OS protections, security software, etc.) But the VM won't protect you.
4. No, JNI existed even before JIT appeared. The mechanism is the same, if the bytecode is being run by an interpreter, and you want this interpreter to invoke native code, you just need some logic in it to determine that a given method is "external" and should be called as native code. This information is contained in the compiled .class file, and when the interpreter or JIT loads it, it creates a memory representation that makes easy to direct the call upon a method lookup.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the platform. On Linux, Solaris, etc., the JRE uses `dlopen`. On Windows, it uses `LoadLibraryEx` and `GetProcAddress`. If the JRE is running in interpreted mode, it calls that function; in compiled mode, it compiles Java bytecode into native code that calls that function.

On all JREs I'm familiar with, you can't call a native function in a static library directly; only one in a dynamic library.

Native code doesn't have to be limited to a single platform; if it's standard C, you can probably compile it with a cross-compiler for every platform on which a JRE is available.

Answer (score 1):

1. The JVM will check the libraries you defined and see if the method is there
2. Bytecode will be interpreted or JITted and a call to native code is added. This may include boxing/deboxing values and other things needed to convert the data into suitable format. The libraries have a certain interface which is explained to the Java compiler and it will produce the required interface logic.
3. Depends on the sandbox. By default native code is native code. It doesn't call Java APIs so the JVM cannot govern it in any way. But there may be other limitations, for example the JVM could run the native code with libraries that provide sandboxing, or the operating system might have a way of sandboxing.
4. It depends on what you mean. In the end anything the computer does is machine code, but it doesn't really matter in this case. What matters is the translation and execution part. That is the glue that makes everything work.

Think of the system as people. Person A only speaks Japanese, but wants to reserve a hotel in Paris. The receptionist B only speaks French. Person A can get a translator that will translate their commands to French, command receptionist B and in return translate what B produced into a form person A understands. This is the JNI part.