# Managed and unmanaged code in .NET

Tags: .net

What is difference between managed code and unmanaged code in terms of the .NET framework?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is managed/unmanaged code in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334326/what-is-managed-unmanaged-code-in-c)

Answer (score 8):

> Managed code is a differentiation
>   created by Microsoft to identify
>   code that requires
>   and will only execute under the
>   "management" of a [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), resulting in
>   [Bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bytecode).
>
> Benefits of using managed code include
>   programmer convenience (by increasing
>   the level of abstraction, creating
>   smaller models) and enhanced security
>   guarantees, depending on the platform
>   (including the VM implementation).

From: [Wikipedia: Managed Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code)

Answer (score 2):

Generally it will refer to memory management.

the `unsafe` keyword will get you there (unmanaged): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288474%28VS.71%29.aspx

As will calling some external functions (`extern` keyword).

Answer (score 0):

Easily answered by Google and Microsoft:
http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/01/09/48925.aspx