# Managed code advantages

Tags: .net, clr, managed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Managed and unmanaged code in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2522190/managed-and-unmanaged-code-in-net)

Hi,
If I am right, then code in my app that runs under CLR (all code written the standard way) is managed code.
But except for GC, what other advantages there are?
I would like to know the real examples (like GC), not theoretical differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Memory management
- Thread management
- Exception handling
- Garbage collection
- Security

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime

Comment: Thanks. How it helpw in terms of security?

Comment: CLR can block access to unauthorised users and also execution of unauthorised code. Adds an additional layer on top of what the OS offers. If you feel like a read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188939.aspx

Answer (score 1):

for example

- no messing with pointers
- no memory management (with some exceptions)
- huge base class library
- able to combine multiple .NET languages