# Opening .dll file and changing it

Tags: c++, dll

I have got file that I need to open, change one value and save(so i need to crack it). Since its **.dll** file i tried to open it with open source decompiler ILSpy. I dont know in what programming language it has been coded.

I am getting "This file does not contain a managed assembly." message.

Any idea what can I do to open that file? Maybe it will be easier if i will upload somewhere that file so you can check it?

Comment: Try to do some "Reverse engineering" on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link that wxplains how to decompile the .dll file. Once the file have been decompiled, it should be easy to edit it.

http://www.wikihow.com/Edit-DLL-Files

Comment: message from .net reflector that is in link you have sent: xxx.dll file is not .NET module :(

Comment: I think the WikiHow page referred to in this answer shows a procedure that only works on .dll files which contain "managed assemblies." @user2618929 stated ILSpy indicates his file is does not contain a managed assembly, so the WikiHow page's instructions are not a solution to this question. See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_code), http://stackoverflow.com/a/3564014/5025060 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/27300147/5025060 for more details.