# What are the differences between managed and unmanaged libraries?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Can you tell me what changes between libraries external managed and unmanaged?
is the exact same thing between managed and unmanaged code?

Comment: I'd imagine it means the same thing, unless you're using "managed external libraries" as something other than an external library with managed code.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563870/difference-between-managed-and-unmanaged

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a managed library contains .NET code (also called an assembly), an unmanaged library contains native code of some sort (C++, VB6 or similar).

*External* usually means that you didn't compile it yourself but use a 3rd party component.

To check whether as assembly is managed or not,

- I open it in [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/). If it is .NET, it will say something like "msil", otherwise "not supported".
- Another option is [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), which will say "This file does not contain a managed assembly."
- The tool *ILDASM* comes with the Windows SDK and says "no valid CLR header" in case of native assemblies.
- You could also see if it has *mscoree* (.NET) as a [dependency](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)

Comment: @missenna: I've added that to my answer. At the moment I think you expected some tools to check for .NET, not some code.

Comment: How do I use dotPeek?

Comment: Any suggestions to what to do about such messages?

Comment: @not2qubit: which messages?

Comment: @ThomasWeller "This file does not contain a managed assembly."

Comment: @not2qubit: The question was how to find out whether or not it's a managed assembly. The message tells that, you confirm the question by a button, you got the information you wanted and the case is solved - isn't it?