# Cannot call to Asp.net WebAPI from Unity app on Android device

Tags: android, dll, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a Unity app run on Android, a DLL plugin to connect to my Asp.net webapi service. 
I've tested it in the Unity Editor and the app can call methods in DLL well, DLL is also connected to api successfully.
However, When I deployed the app to my phone and debug the server, there's no connection being made from the phone.
I've installed the app Network Log to check the network activity of my app but didn't see any activity made.
So, how can I figure out where the root of problem is?
Is DLL possible to use in Android unity app?

**UPDATE:** It turned out that only my project have this problem. The DLL we developed by ourselves but my friend implemented it to connect successfully to API on Android. But I didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have to put them under Libs folder in Assets to make it works on Android

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to use .dlls on Android, but there are some changes with Unity 5.

Maybe this [article](http://ericeastwood.com/blog/17/unity-and-dlls-c-managed-and-c-unmanaged) can help you.

Comment: In my case. Do I need a unmannaged library? Because the only things the mannaged C# DLL file do is connecting to server and get back the result. I tried to copy my DLL to Plugins folder, however, couldn't using it in code

Comment: You can read something about it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563870/difference-between-managed-and-unmanaged)

I think you need an unmanaged .dll (x64) and then write a c# Unity wrapper for it as described in the [article](http://ericeastwood.com/blog/17/unity-and-dlls-c-managed-and-c-unmanaged)

Comment: it turned out that although using the same DLL file we created by ourselves. My friends could use it to connect to API succesfully, but I didn't