# How to see in HttpContext whether a request was made to managed/unmanaged resource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm developing an IIS module that is supposed to be triggered when a request is made to all kind of pages on my webserver (managed and unmanaged). To accomplish that I implemented the `IHttpModule` interface that has a method called `HandleRequest` which have to be implemented. In the method context I have access to an `HttpApplication` object and `HttpContext` object.
Is there any indication in these objects or any other place to tell if the request that is now being handled by the module was issued to a managed page (e.g aspx,asmx,web-api,mvc,wcf) or to an unmanaged page (e.g jpg,css,htm..).

Here is the code:

```
public class MyPreIISReqeustModule : System.Web.IHttpModule
{
  public void Dispose()
    {

    }

  public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(HandleRequest);
    }
  protected void HandleRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (managed_page_request)
           {......}
        else
           {......}
    }
 }
```

Comment: Does this make sense ? I mean, if managed code is code that runs under the CLR, and the code above ALWAYS runs under the CLR, this program will always be managed... ?

Comment: I have to be able to make this distinction between resources that have to be returned immediately, and calls to web-services, and other managed handlers, for reasons of logging,caching and etc. knowing which page doesn't have code behind it will help me avoid unnecessary processing work.

Comment: I don't know, I am not familiar with this topic. I just thought aloud.

Comment: I think you are using the term `managed` incorrectly. Managed means that the code offers garbage collection, runtime checking, reference checks etc. See [Difference between “managed” and “unmanaged”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563870/difference-between-managed-and-unmanaged). I think you need to pick a more appropriate term in your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: under the context of asp.net this term describes my needs accurately. this term is also used by official iis/asp.net documentation to make the same distinction about the behavior of the  entities that iis exposes to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I've found myself in the same situation and am unable to find any simple property that indicates whether the request is managed or not. So what I've done is to check if the file in the Request exists on the file system or not. If it exists, then I assume this is not a managed request; otherwise it is. So, in your HandleRequest() method:

```
HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)source;

if (!System.IO.File.Exists(application.Request.PhysicalPath)) {
    // file does not exist; assume this is a managed request
} else{
    // file does exist; so this request isn't managed
}
```

It might not be perfect but it works well for my needs. Edge cases you could probably handle explicitly.

Comment: I realize this question is nearly a decade old but it is somehow still relevant.