# How to invoke a method in list of object in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

This is First Project of Class 1:

```
namespace project1;

public static class Pjo
{
    List<object> list1 = new List<object>();
    static Pab abstate;
    static Pcd cdstate;
    public static Pab Abstate { get; set; }
    public static Pcd Cdstate { get; set; }
    public static List<object> List1 { get; set; }
    public static void initialise(string elementname)
    {
        Pab = new Library();
        List1.add(Pab);
        Pcd = new Libre();
        List1.add(Pcd);
    }
}
```

This is First Project of Second class

```
public class process
{
    foreach(var item in Pjo.List1)
    {
        Type type = typeof("project1.Pjo");
        Methodinfo m = type.GetMethod();// i need to invoke Library File Method. Ex:pab1() 
    }
}
```

This is another project of class

```
namespace Lib
{
    public class Library
    {
        int n1;
        int n2;
        public int N1 { get; set; }
        public int N2 { get; set; }
        public void Library1()
        {
            int n3;
            n3 = n1 + n2;
        }
    }
    public class Libre
    {
        int a1;
        int a2;
        public int A1 { get; set; }
        public int A2 { get; set; }
        public void Libre1()
        {
            int a3;
            a3 = a1 + a2;
        }
    }
}
```

How to invoke the method using reflection or other method list of object in c#
List of object i passing the foreach loop and i get the type of class but i can't get to invoke the method. please anyone have clear the doubt.

Comment: Tip: Indent your code to make it more readable.

Comment: See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991689/c-sharp-call-a-method-by-memory-address

Comment: you already have MethodInfo m; and ask how to call m.Invoke() ? Call m.Invoke(); But if you have typeof for a type, than Reflection is not necessary, if it's all known at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

I would imagine that the list contains objects with something in common (i.e. the method you want to invoke).

Why don't you create an interface?

```
public interface ISomething 
{
    void MethodToInvoke();
}
```

Then, instead of a list of objects, you'd have:

```
list<ISomething> list1 = ...
```

And you call the method defined in the interface:

```
foreach(ISomething item in new Pjo().List1)
{
    item.MethodToInvoke();
}
```