# How to loop through class objects in C++

Tags: c++

My question is How can I have combat for all enemies by having only 1 function?

At the moment I create my enemies by writing `Enemy` (class) and giving it `object + number` name, then I just give some inputs and it looks like:

```
Enemy object1(1, 20, '/', "AQUA", 1);
Enemy object2(5, 40, '/', "YELLOW", 2);
Enemy object3(10, 60, '/', "WHITE", 3);
```

Then I have a runtime for Combat and I run an awful while loop:

```
while (object1.getHp() > 0)
```

to run my combat code.

So now I need to have just one combat function to run all different enemies, I already tried a lot of  thing but nothing seems to work. Any idea on what can I do?

Sounds and looks dumb but I really can't guess anything to do about it, already lost tons of hours looking for a solution.

Comment: Why can't you put all your objects in a container probably something like a `std::vector<Enemy*>` and loop through all these objects.

Comment: That's what containers like arrays and vectors are for. You know how to use an array right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need first is a [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) able to hold your `Enemy` instances or pointers to them. Most containers are templated classes, which have to be typed. One of them is the [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (a contiguous 'list'), which can be created in your case as

- `std::vector<Enemy>`: A 'list' holding your full objects
- `std::vector<Enemy*>`: A 'list' holding pointers to your objects

An example if you take references from your objects:

```
std::vector<Enemy*> enemies;
enemies.push_back(&object1);
enemies.push_back(&object2);
enemies.push_back(&object3);
```

If you are not familiar with pointers, you can look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer), even though it may be a bit opaque at first!

#### Looping

A range for loop will let you iterate over your container pretty easily

```
for ( auto enemy : enemies ) {
    enemy->doStuff();
}
```

The `auto` will deduce the type from the container, and `doStuff` will be executed sequentially for every enemy in your list. If your container contains instances instead of pointers `*`, you will need to take a reference `&` of the object instead, and use `for ( auto& enemy : enemies )`. This will ensure your object is modified in place, and not copied, otherwise, your changes won't get reflected in the container.

#### Memory management

As mentioned in other answers, when you are ready to move to the next level, you can have a look at [smart pointers](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers). Because C++ code is [unmanaged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563870/difference-between-managed-and-unmanaged) and has no out-of-the-box memory management, *you* are responsible for `delete`ing any `new`ed object. Smart pointers will help you more safely manage the lifespan of your data. Raw pointers (without any smart pointer to protect them) are considered bad practice in most situations nowadays.

However, your `Enemy` instances are created on the stack, so they will get automatically destroyed at the end of their scope (function, `{}`, ...). This also means that if you have any pointer `*` or references to them that you use outside this scope, your object has been destroyed already, and you will encounter a memory exception or undefined behavior, i.e. Don't do that!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to group your objects like this:

```
std::vector<Enemy> vEnemies
{
    { 1,  20, '/', "AQUA",   1 },
    { 5,  40, '/', "YELLOW", 2 },
    { 10, 60, '/', "WHITE",  3 }
};
```

And, then you can use C++11's [range-for](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop for all the objects:

```
for ( auto& e : vEnemies )
{
    e.doSomething();
}
```

You may also explore [std::for_each](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) for your other use-cases.

---

If you're looking for a solution with pointers e.g. `std::vector<Enemy*>` then you ought to first look at smart pointers ([std::unique_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) / [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) along with [std::make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) / [std::make_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared)) to enforce [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) for your objects allocated on the heap / free-store.

Answer (score 1):

Please find the rough instructions below to solve your problem.

- Store all objects inside an array or advanced structures like vector.
- Set a flag to indicate if there is at least one enemy alive
- Run a while loop as long as flag remains true

  - set flag to false
  - For each object in array,
  - Check if health point more than zero

    - Then perform your action
    - set flat to true

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Define a container of enemies preferably a `std::vector<Enemy>` and iterate over all the objects in the container.

```
std::vector<Enemy> enemies;
// Now construct your enemies in the vector.
enemies.emplace_back(1, 20, '/', "AQUA", 1);
enemies.emplace_back(1, 20, '/', "YELLOW", 2);
.
.
// Now loop through.
for (auto & enemy: enemies) {
  enemy.Combat(); // Whatever you want
}
```