# What does managed and unmanaged code mean ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between “managed” vs “unmanaged”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563870/what-is-the-difference-between-managed-vs-unmanaged)

Hi, could you please help to understand the mean of

```
managed and unmanaged code?
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3563870/what-is-the-difference-between-managed-vs-unmanaged

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this previous SO post can help:
[What is managed/unmanaged code in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334326/what-is-managed-unmanaged-code-in-c)