# Windows 8 - WriteTextAsync exception "Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack."

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro, unity-game-engine

I want to use StorageFile, to implement Reading & Writing as seen here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758325.aspx#writing_to_a_file

With

```
public async void Save()
{
    StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
    StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(PlayerPrefs.GetString("WorldName") +"_"+filename);
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "Swift as a shadow");
}
```

But the "await" line gives the exception

```
+    $exception {Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack.} System.Exception {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}
```

I'm using Unity with Windows 8 Store if this makes any difference.

Anyone know what the problem is here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack
```

That only tells us that the thread is executing [unmanaged code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334326/what-is-managed-unmanaged-code-in-c), hence it cannot evaluate the expression.

The real error is the `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.

So open your *Package.appxmanifest*, go to the *Capabilities* tab and check *Document Library Access*.

Answer (score 0):

Just create test certificate and check "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" in Signing option in Solution properties with right click on solution name in solution explorer.